# C# Universal app - RSS in condig windows-1250

Tags: c#, rss, win-universal-app

im buld universal app with feed. But feed is in encoding Windows-1250 (http://www.muzikus.cz/save/rss-windows-1250.xml). Haw to fix showing all characters?

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        getFeed("http://www.muzikus.cz/save/rss-windows-1250.xml");

    }

    public async Task<String> getFeed(String feedUrl)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(feedUrl));
            var xmlString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var dialog = new MessageDialog("Output: " + xmlString );
            await dialog.ShowAsync();

            return jsonString;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you returning jsonString from the getFeed function when you are reading in xmlString?